# Pyparsing language with AND, NOT and OR

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to make a simple language with 3 operators: AND, NOT and OR.
The goal of this language is to specify which words will be accepted in an url.
Example:

```
word1 AND (word2 OR word3)
```

This expression means I'd be accepting urls containing word1 + word2 or urls containing word1 + word3.
Example with NOT:

```
word1 or (word2 AND NOT(word3))
```

This one means I would accept urls containing word1 or if it contains word2 but not word3.

Here's what I have done for now:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, oneOf
import pyparsing as pp

lparen = pp.Suppress("(")
rparen = pp.Suppress(")")

and_ = pp.Literal("AND")
or_ = pp.Literal("OR")
not_ = pp.Literal("NOT")

expr = pp.Forward()

alphaword = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_")
not_condition =  (not_ + lparen + alphaword + rparen)
condition =  not_condition | alphaword | (lparen + expr + rparen)
and_condition =  condition +  pp.ZeroOrMore(and_ + condition)
or_condition =  condition +  pp.ZeroOrMore(or_ + condition)

condition.setDebug(True)

expr <<  and_condition| or_condition | condition

t = "equipe AND shoes AND tennis AND NOT (foot) AND (tvee OR tfee)"
c = expr.parseString(t)
print(c)
```

With the example "equipe AND shoes AND tennis AND NOT (foot) AND (tvee OR tfee)", I'm getting the following output:

['lequipe', 'AND', 'shoes', 'AND', 'tennis', 'AND', 'NOT', 'foot']

So the last part (the OR) seems to be skipped.

Here are examples of what I expect to be able to parse:

```
# lequipe.fr
# not(samsung)
# lequipe.fr AND shoes
# lequipe.fr AND shoes AND tv
# lequipe.fr AND not(pc) AND apple
# tf1.fr AND (pc or tv) 
# word1 or (word2 and word3)
# word1 or (word2 and (word4 or word5)) or word3
# word1 OR (word AND (word3 OR word4))
```

Can someone help correct this please ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [pyparsing documentation on pyparsing.Forward](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html#pyparsing.Forward)

> Note: take care when assigning to `Forward` not to overlook precedence of operators.
>
> Specifically, `|` has a lower precedence than `<<`, so that:
>
> ```
> fwdExpr << a | b | c
> ```
>
> will actually be evaluated as:
>
> ```
> (fwdExpr << a) | b | c
> ```
>
> thereby leaving b and c out as parseable alternatives. It is recommended that you explicitly group the values inserted into the `Forward`:
>
> ```
> fwdExpr << (a | b | c)
> ```

Compare that advice with your:

```py
expr <<  and_condition| or_condition | condition
```

Comment: An important point! Future release of pyparsing will include diagnostic warning to help flag if this common error is present.

Answer (score 0):

A good beginning, but there are some pieces missing here beyond just changing '<<' to '<<='.

To build up your operations with the correct precedence, you need to
build them up by referring to the previous level of operator precedence.
So instead of:

```
and_condition =  condition +  pp.ZeroOrMore(and_ + condition)
or_condition =  condition +  pp.ZeroOrMore(or_ + condition)
```

you would write:

```
and_condition =  condition +  pp.ZeroOrMore(and_ + condition)
or_condition =  and_condition  +  pp.ZeroOrMore(or_ + and_condition)
```

To preserve the hierarchical precedence of operations in the parsed results, then
you wrap each level in Group:

```
# build up the hierarchy of expressions to implement proper precedence of operators
# use Group to group terms together at each level of precedence
and_condition =  Group(condition +  pp.ZeroOrMore(and_ + condition))
or_condition =  Group(and_condition  +  pp.ZeroOrMore(or_ + and_condition))
```

A slight downside to this is that *everything* gets grouped, even if there are no operators
present. You can avoid this extraneous grouping by only using Group if an operator
is used, else just parse the next level operation.

```
# for cleaner output, only group terms when an operator is actually present
and_condition =  Group(condition +  pp.OneOrMore(and_ + condition)) | condition
or_condition =  Group(and_condition  +  pp.OneOrMore(or_ + and_condition))  | and_condition
```

Now it is no longer necessary to use all the different levels in `expr`, just `or_condition`.
All the other levels are embedded in each higher-level operation:

```
# expr <<=  and_condition| or_condition | condition
expr <<= or_condition
```

I redid your test code using `expr.runTests` - it makes it easier to add new tests, and I
think you'll find the output helpful.

```
expr.runTests("""\
    equipe AND shoes AND tennis AND NOT (foot)
    equipe AND tennis AND (shoes AND NOT (foot) OR racket OR balls)
    """)
```

I thought I saw somewhere a different pass at this problem using the
`infixNotation` helper method. `infixNotation` allows you to focus on the operators
and their definitions, and takes care of all the grouping, referencing, overrides using ()'s,
and recursion:

```
expr = pp.infixNotation(alphaword,
                        [
                        (not_, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                        (and_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                        (or_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                        ])
```

No Forward() definition required, nor all the intermediate expressions for each level
of operator precedence.

Lastly, you may find that parsing performance with recursive parsers for infix notation is slow. You can speed them up by enabling pyparsing's internal cacheing, called *packrat parsing*:

```
pp.ParserElement.enablePackrat()
```

Good luck!